# How to compare two unix time in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to check the start time and end time using unix time format in flutter.
I have a time x, I need to check the 'x' time is between 'y' and 'z' or equal to 'y' and 'z'.

**Note : The x,y,z times are in unix time format.**

Comment: You can create DateTime object from your unix timestamp by using this method DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch and then you can use isBefore and isAfter method of DateTime to compare

Comment: A unix time is just a number. When a number higher than another then it's later. Just check if x >= y and x <= z. Don't even need DateTime objects for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      static bool calculateTimeDiff(int yourtime, String givenY,
          String givenZ) {
                //your time, if your time in X in second 
        int x = yourtime;
             //if your your time is unix;
        String yDate = givenY.replaceAll('T', ' ');
        String zDate = givenZ.replaceAll('T', ' ');
    
    
        // parse date into standard datetime formate
        DateTime parseYDate =
        new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(yDate);
        DateTime parseZDate =
        new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(zDate);
    
        // convert date time into second
        int y = parseYDate.second;
        int z = parseZDate.second;

//if x,y,z all are integer value no need write above code. use just below code
        if (x >= y && x <= z) {
          return true;
        } else if (x == y||x==z) {
          return true;
        } 
    
        return false;
      }
```

Comment: how can I add 120 minutes to the 'x' time?

Comment: 1 minute = 60 seconds. so  int x =120*60;

Comment: I need to add 1663862400000 + 120 minutes.